# Flutter FutureBuilder show Progress indicator

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I have a button which onpressed inserts something in DB and redirects user to another page. I am trying to implement FutureBuilder which should show `CircularProgressIndicator` until everything is done.

This is my function:

```
Future<bool> insertPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    String token = await getToken();

    if (token.isNotEmpty) {
      var body = jsonEncode({'token': token, 'userID': user.getUserID(), 'phoneNumber': phoneNumber});

      print(body.toString());

      var res = await http.post((baseUrl + "/insertPhoneNumber/" + user.getUserID()),
          body: body,
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json"
          });

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Insert Phone Number is OK");
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      } else {
        print("Insert Phone Number not OK");
        notifyListeners();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      print("Insert Phone Number failed due to unexisting token");
    }
  }
```

and this is a button which triggers DB interaction:

```
RaisedButton(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(105, 79, 150, 1),
                  onPressed: () {
                    var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
                    String completePhoneNumber = _selectedDialogCountry.phoneCode + phoneNumberController.text;
                    FutureBuilder(
                      future: user.insertPhoneNumber(completePhoneNumber),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blue);
                        } else {
                          return Dashboard();
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Text("SAVE"),
                )
```

It updates DB but nothing else happens. There is no progress indicator nor redirection to `Dashboard`.

**EDIT**

This is my full build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              AutoSizeText(
                'What is your phone number?',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 9.0,
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                  SizedBox(
                      width: 120.0,
                      height: 65.0,
                      child: Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          onTap: _openCountryPickerDialog,
                          title: _buildDialogItem(_selectedDialogCountry),
                        ),
                      )),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder())),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(105, 79, 150, 1),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("Test");
                  },
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Text("SAVE"),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you show the full class where your mentioned RaisedButton() is defined? And did you try using hasError() on AsyncSnapshot  to get possible problems with the async functions?

Comment: I've edited my question and posted full `build` method. It is simple class `PhoneNumber` and `build` is inside `PhoneNumberState` class.

Comment: Hi.have you found any solution?I have similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

It is not working because the `FutureBuilder` isn't attached to the Widget tree.
The once the future is not in done state, it is just creating an instance `Dashboard`.You shouldn't be using `FutureBuilder` here instead you can set the child widget based on some variable and when future complete, you call `setState` on the that variable to update the state which will in-turn rebuild the widget with the new state value

Something like this

```dart
var isLoading = false;

void insertNumber(){
 var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
 String completePhoneNumber = _selectedDialogCountry.phoneCode + phoneNumberController.text;
 setState(() => isLoading=true);
 user.insertPhoneNumber(completePhoneNumber).then((result){
  setState(() => isLoading=false);
 })
}

Widget build(BuildContext context){
 return RaisedButton(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(105, 79, 150, 1),
                  onPressed: () {
                    var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
                    String completePhoneNumber = _selectedDialogCountry.phoneCode + phoneNumberController.text;
                    FutureBuilder(
                      future: user.insertPhoneNumber(completePhoneNumber),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blue);
                        } else {
                          return Dashboard();
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  child: isLoading? CircularProgressIndicator(): Text("Save"),
                );
}
```

For your use case, you will need more that two state to achieve the UI you are looking for .Example `DEFAULT`,`LOADING`,`ERROR`,`SUCCESS`

Comment: Why is his code not attached to the widget tree. You cant see from his code sample if RaisedButton is in the build() method can you?

Comment: Since `FutureBuilder` is a `Widget`, it should be a child on some parent `Widget` in order to be part of  Widget Tree.Here you are just creating an instance of `FutureBuilder`